# How to import the mdi icons module inside nuxt.config.js in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have installed the https://materialdesignicons.com/ with

```
npm install @mdi/font
```

**In nuxt.config.js file, I am not sure how to import the icons module... Please help!**

```
export default {
    build: {
      /*
       ** You can extend webpack config here
       */

      extend(config, ctx) {}
    },
    buildModules: [
      // Simple usage
      '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  
      // With options
    //  ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { /* module options */ }]
    ]
}
```

Here is an example of a Vuetify tab using a MDI icon.

```
<v-icon large color="blue darken-2">mdi-message-text</v-icon>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by adding `@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css` into your `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```js
export default {
    css : [
       '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
    ],
    build: {
      /*
       ** You can extend webpack config here
       */

      extend(config, ctx) {}
    }
    /* Rest of configs */
}
```

And if you use Vuetify *(I see you used it)* Then add `iconfont: 'mdi'` in Vuetify module configuration, like this:

```js
export default {
    css : [
       '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
    ],
    buildModules: [
      '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
      ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { iconfont: 'mdi' }]
    ]
    /* Rest of configs */
}
```

Comment: This actually made me score worse on lighthouse.. :/ i am trying a way to be better, cause vuetify is just BAD!

Comment: How would this be done using the 'md' package instead, e.g the custom repo which vuetify docs talk about: https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont
Been trying different solutions but can't seem to get it right

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by SMAKSS worked, but i had to configure `defaultAssets: false` in vuetify module configuration to avoid download from CDNs.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultassets