# Vuetify + Nuxt + locally add md icons

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

How would one import the 'md' icons locally, similar to how they import the mdi ones in this post:
[How to import the mdi icons module inside nuxt.config.js in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206283/how-to-import-the-mdi-icons-module-inside-nuxt-config-js-in-nuxt)

Either the standard package or the custom repo
https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont
I'm using the nuxt-vuetify plugin.
All my attempts have failed, e.g adding this:

nuxt.config.js

```
css: ['~/assets/main.css', './node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'],

vuetify: {
  customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  treeShake: true,
  defaultAssets: {
    font: false,
    icons: 'md',// this just fetches it from the repo
// icons: {iconfont: 'md'} // this doesn't seem to work for me
    enter code here
    },
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: '#fec655',
        },
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Vuetify has material icons integrated. I am also developing in vuejs, nuxtjs. I just installed font using this command ```npm install @mdi/font -D``` and i can use any material icon ```mdi-iconname``` inside ```v-icon```. check this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/

Comment: Yes, but this is about the 'md' library and not the mdi one :). Adding md vs. mdi locally ended up just being about switching out the global css import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving it right after I posted it.
In the end, the settings in the original questions are correct.
One simply has to install the 'md' package from the original source or https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont

After that, it's just a matter of changing the global CSS import.
E.g
css: ['./node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'],

A sidenote is that it seems to be possible to use both 'md' and 'mdi' by installing mdi/js for the treeshaken version & making imports manually.
This way, you can use the default icons for all the components but still add more icons from MDI if needed. Since the 'mdi' bundle is around 330kb while the 'md' one is only around 80kb this saves quite a lot of space.